# Getting empty 3d plot for NDSolve solution

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

Greeting
I am trying to numerically solve a differential equation expressed in a code below, as an analytical solution is not feasible (probably, correct me if I am wrong)

`z1,z2`- are actually the functions of time and should be within boundaries `{z1,0,tmax*G`}`,`where `G` - any positive constant. However, in the code below me trying to treat them as a

The terminal condition for the `b=b(tmax)=-P`. `b(t)` is a non-zero value.

Ane help will be appreciated. Probably, I have done a lot of newbies mistakes again.

Thank you very much!

The code:

```
 ClearAll["Global`*"]
tmax = 10; r = 0.5; lambda = 0.3; P = 20;


j = D[b[t, z1, z2], t] + (3/2 + z2^2 + z1^2)*b[t, z1, z2]^2*lambda^2*
    Exp[r*t] + (1 + z1^2)*b[t, z1, z2]*P*lambda^2*Exp[r*t] == 0


s = NDSolve[ {j , b[tmax, z1, z2] == -P}, b, {t, 0, tmax}, {z1, 0, 100}, {z2, 0, 100}]

Plot3D[b[t, z1, 100], {t, 0, tmax}, {z1, 0, 100}]
```

Comment: You missed to use the solution in Plot3D. Plot3D[b[t, z1, 100] /. s, {t, 0, tmax}, {z1, 0, 100}] works

Comment: Probably, that is all

Comment: I have another stupid question:

I now need to use the solution of the NDsolve (b) to estimate my value function, and plot it for {z1, 0, 100}, {z2, 0, 100}:

V = b[t, z1, z2]*Exp[-lambda*(z1 + z2)] + P*Exp[lambda*z2] 

What is the appropriate command to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with getting an empty plot has been answered by @Lotus.

My response is to the OP's comment regrading calling the numerical solution outside of the `NDSolve` into an expression and then plotting it. For this purpose, I have used `SetDelay` like this,

```
f[t_, z1_, z2_] := (b /. s[[1, 1]])[t, z1, z2];

V[t_, z1_, z2_] := f[t, z1, z2]*Exp[-lambda*(z1 + z2)] + P*Exp[lambda*z2];

Plot3D[V[1, z1, z2], {z1, 0, 100}, {z2, 0, 100}]
```

Since OP has not mentioned a specific value for `t`, so I choose a random one here.